# Pass a list of directories to a find command

Tags: command-line

How can I pass a list of directories to a find command?

Imagine you got the list as:

```
ls -d mydir*/
```

which would output mydir1, mydir2 and so on, but exclude otherdirs1, otherdirs2.

I'd like to run the following command on the list:

```
find <put here the name of each dir>  -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

Trying to run this command on each directory separately:

```
find -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 |
xargs -0  mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify 2>/dev/null |
 perl -nle '/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/ && ($t +=$1) && printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/3600,$t/60%60,$t%60' |
 tail -n 1
```

That means: find the mp3s, run mplayer to obtain meta-data on each file, sum all ID_LENGTH of each mp3 file, output sum of all mp3s in directory.

Answer (score 3):

`ls -d` lists exactly what you passed it (except for the non-existing files). So assuming that there is at least one directory whose name begins with `mydir`, it's simply

```
find mydir*/ -type f -name .mp3 -print0 | …
```

Note that `mydir*/` matches symbolic links to directories, and `find` will traverse the linked directories.

Normally `xargs` runs the command as few times as possible, passing it multiple arguments at a time. If you need to run the command for each file separately, tell it so:

```
find mydir*/ -type f -name .mp3 -print0 |
xargs -0 -n1 mplayer … |
perl …
```

Or do the simple thing and use the `-exec` option of `find`. You do lose the ability to filter the errors from `find` and from `mplayer` separately.

```
find mydir*/ -type f -name .mp3 -exec mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify {} \; 2>/dev/null |
perl …
```

By the way, why print all the lines if you only need the last one?

```
… | perl -nle '/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/ && ($t +=$1); END {printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/3600,$t/60%60,$t%60}'
```

In bash after running `shopt -s globstar`, in ksh after running `set -o globstar`, or in zsh out of the box, you can also use `**` to match files in subdirectories recursively.

```
mycommand mydir*/**/*.mp3
for f in mydir*/**/*.mp3; do …
```

This also matches directories and symbolic links whose name ends in `.mp3`. Bash traverses symbolic links to directories while ksh and zsh do traverse `mydir*` if they're symbolic links to directories but omit symbolic links when recursing.

```
for f in mydir*/**/*.mp3; do
  mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify "$f" 2>/dev/null
done | perl …
```

ksh93 and zsh (but not bash, dash or pdksh) have floating point arithmetic, so you don't even need to invoke another tool such as Perl to do the sum.

```
typeset -F length=0
for f in mydir*/**/*.mp3; do
  length+=$(mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify "$f" 2>/dev/null |
            sed -n 's/^ID_LENGTH=//p')
done | perl …
printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $((t/3600)) $((t/60%60)) $((t%60))
```

Comment: Yes, that helps. However, I still have to run the find command on each single directory separately. The xargs's part above is:     find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0  mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify 2>/dev/null | perl -nle '/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/ && ($t +=$1) && printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/3600,$t/60%60,$t%60' | tail -n 1
So, I want to know the output of each command, for example mydir1: 4:44, mydir2: 81:33 and so on.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your command without formatting. Do you want to run `mplayer` once per directory or once per mp3 file? If it's once per directory, then call the pipeline in a loop: `for d in mydir*/; do find "$d" -name .mp3 -print0 | xargs …`. If it's once per file, then you don't need to run separate `find` commands: you need to tell `xargs` to run a new instance of `mplayer` for each file, or simpler, use `-exec` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: Ok, I expanded my question, explaining better the command. It has to run mplayer on each file.

Comment: @QuoraFea See my updated answer.

Comment: that's OK for knowing the total length of all mp3, but still leaves me without knowing a break down by each directory. How can I generate a table as dir1: 12:02, dir2: 03:45 and so on?

Comment: @QuoraFea Then iterate over the directories (I show how in my answer), and for each directory, do the sum (you already know how to do it).